# Install app in Apple Watch before submission for testing

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I need to test the Apple Watch app. App is working fine in simulator. how can we install in device and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pair Your `iPhone` & `Apple Watch`, setup your provisioning profiles for `Watch-app` & `extention` NOW....

Apps that include `aplle-Watch-extention` should automatically start installation on `Watch` when you start `iPhone App` (Parent App) installation.

[Here is the Video Link that illustrate briefly](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/apple-watch-apps-how-to-install-how-to-delete-how-they-work/)

[Second Link for more detail](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/117350678170/jareds-code-signing-tips-apple-watch-edition)

Hope it'll help you... :)

Comment: Thanks Zubair. second link has more data.